# Can "Phantom Knights's Sword" Prevent a monster from being destroyed because of "Call of the Haunted"?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

So let's say I use "Call of the Haunted" to summon a monster from my GY. Then I equip "Phantom Knights Sword" to it. So now that monster gains 800 ATK and if it were to be destroyed, I can destroy "Phantom Knights Sword" instead. If "Call of the Haunted" is destroyed, however, then the monster I summoned with it will also be destroyed. But can I still use "Phantom Knight's Sword" to prevent that monster from being destroyed? And if yes, then what happens to "Call of the Haunted?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "Call of the Haunted" and "Phantom Knights' Sword" would be destroyed. You can use the effect of "Phantom Knights's Sword" to prevent the monster from being destroyed because it is a continuous effect. "Call of the Haunted" will be destroyed as per normal.